# Quitar combinación Celdas y copiar. InputBox para seleccion de rangos

Tags: vba

Estoy intentando quitar una combinación de celdas y mantener el contenido de forma individual para cada una, el problema que tengo es que tengo el rango fijo y quiero que lo pida por pantalla.

Lo que tengo ahora con el rango fijo es:

```
Sub Descombinar()

Set rango = Range("A2:A1000") 'aqui ponemos el rango, se podría hacer con un inputbox para seleccionarlo

Range ("A2:A1000") 'aqui ponemos el rango, se podría hacer con un inputbox para seleccionarlo
With rango 'para este rango

    .UnMerge 'descombina

    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

    .Copy

    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'copy-paste con valores

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set rango = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Primer debes acostumbrarte a declarar todas tus variables, para ello te recomiendo que encima de cada módulo pongas `Option Explicit` así te forzará a declarar las variables.

Lo de pedir al usuario que escriba el rango puede dar lugar a muchos errores... No hay otra forma de hacer esto? Si quieres elegir columna sería menos peligroso, aún así ahí va el código:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Descombinar()

    Dim Rango As Range, C As Range
    Dim RangoSTR As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    RangoSTR = InputBox("Introduce el rango con formato A1:A1000", "Introduce el rango")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja") 'Cambia el nombre a la hoja de trabajo
        On Error Resume Next 'contingencia por si el input del usuario está mal
        Set Rango = .Range(RangoSTR) 'aqui ponemos el rango, se podría hacer con un inputbox para seleccionarlo
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Rango Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Has puesto mal el rango, vuelve a ejecutar la macro e inténtalo de nuevo."
            End
        End If
        Rango.UnMerge 'descombina
        For Each C In Rango
            If C = vbNullString Then C = C.Offset(-1)
        Next C
    End With

    Set Rango = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracías @Damián. Va perfecto, si la verdad que no lo uso habitualmente pero tengo que acostumbrarme a poner explicit option... tengo un poco de follón entre php, js, vba...etc.etc.. Creo que lo que comentas de seleccionar una columna será lo mejor. saludos,

Comment: @jesus si te ha servido no olvides aceptar la respuesta. En cuanto a lo del rango, si pudiera ver el rango en cuestión (si es porque el rango crece o disminuye, no hace falta ni si quiera input del usuario) podríamos afinar más.